# Dynamic calculate the total

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, formula, addition

I have the following question: cellA12=subtotal, cell c12= 23 , cell A40= subtotal, cell c40= 12 , cell A60 = subtotal, cell C60= 50. Cell B80 = grand total, cell c80= C12-C40+c60

But every month, the location of cell A  include “subtotal” and Cell include the number and cell B is change every month. Could I have formula or VBA script to make it dynamic that first subtotal minus second subtotal and add third subtotal every month?

Regards,
Joe

Comment: Not following you.  A subtotal shouldn't include another subtotal.  If values in `A2:A4` with a subtotal in `A5`, and then more figures followed by another subtotal - the second subtotal doesn't include the first subtotal figure, just the base figures.

Comment: Thank Darren. My description of question is not good enough for your understanding. Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function SubtotalOperations(rng As Range) As Double
  Dim FindSubtotal As Range, firstOne As String, subTCount As Long
  Dim subTCalculate As Double, firstSubt As Double, secondSubt As Double
  
   With rng
    Set FindSubtotal = .Find("SUBTOTAL", After:=.cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart) 'first subtotal found
    If Not FindSubtotal Is Nothing Then
            firstOne = FindSubtotal.Address  'cell address of the first subtotal
            Do
                subTCount = subTCount + 1 'count the found subtotals
                If subTCount = 1 Then
                        firstSubt = FindSubtotal.Value
                ElseIf subTCount = 2 Then
                        secondSubt = FindSubtotal.Value - firstSubt
                ElseIf subTCount = 3 Then
                        SubtotalOperations = FindSubtotal.Value + secondSubt: Exit Function
                End If
                Set FindSubtotal = .FindNext(FindSubtotal)
            Loop While FindSubtotal.Address <> firstOne 'loop until reaching first found subtotal cell address
        End If
   End With
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testSubtOperations()
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   MsgBox SubtotalOperations(sh.Range("A:A"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Is using `Named Range` available in this case @FaneDuru  ?

Comment: @Waleed Always a range can  be replaced by a named range, but witch to be the  named one in the above code context, to make some sense? Only `rng` exists, except `FindSubtotal`, which is variable/unknown, so it is beyond the discussion...